# Terraform - How to Create a GKE Cluster and Install Helm Charts?

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, nginx-ingress

## Goal

I have a specific workflow to set up a fresh Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud. And I want to automate the process with Terraform. Those are the steps:

1. Create cluster

   ```
   gcloud beta container --project "my-google-project" clusters create "cluster-name" --zone "europe-west3-b"
   ```
2. Setup Helm repos

   ```
   helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
   helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io/
   helm repo update
   ```
3. Install NGINX Ingress

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
   helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress
   ```
4. Install Cert-Manager

   ```
   kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/v0.13.0/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml
   kubectl create namespace cert-manager
   helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager
   ```

## Ideas

The first step will probably look like this:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "cluster-name"
  location           = "europe-west3-b"
  initial_node_count = 3

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to approach steps 2 - 4.

Comment: Steps 2-4 are software provisioning and should be performed with a software provisioner instead. The most popular tool for that is Ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Terraform makes sense for building and provisioning cloud infrastructure for things like Kubernetes to run on, it doesn't necessarily make sense to be used to configure said infrastructure after deployment. I think most infrastructure designs would consider applications deployed onto a provisioned cluster as configurations to said cluster. The semantics here are surely a bit nuanced but I maintain that a tool like Ansible is better suited to deploy applications to your cluster after provisioning.

So my advice would be to define a handful of Ansible Roles. Perhaps:

```
create_cluster
deploy_helm
install_nginx_ingress
install_cert_manager
```

Within each respective role, define the tasks and variables that are required to be used as per the [Galaxy schema](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_role.html). Lastly, define a [Playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_roles.html) that Ansible uses to `include` or `import` these roles. This would allow you to provision your infrastructure and deploy all of the required applications to it in a single command:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml`